# how to linear translation smoothly between two game objects in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Actually i new in unity trying to  learn Linear Translation  smoothly.I use two cubes  and trying to  translate linear smoothly  each other.

```
public class LinearTrasnformation : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject cube1, cube2;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //cube1.transform.position = new Vector3 (cube1.transform.position.x,cube1.transform.position.y,cube1.transform.position.z);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () { 
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
            cube1.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (cube2.transform.position,cube1.transform.position,0.5f*Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The last component of the Lerp can be thought of as the fraction of completion of the lerp (from 0 to 1). You will also need to store the original position of cube 1, otherwise the lerp will continously be updated using the new position of the cube. You should instead do...

```
float t = 0;
Vector2 origpos;

void Start() {

}
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
          origpos = cube1.transform.position; //store position on keydown      
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        cube1.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(origpos, cube2.transform.position, t/2f); // where 2f is the amount of time you want the transition to take
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow) 
        t = 0; // reset timer on key up
}
```